# Spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I am using Spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE version with hazelcast.

I am trying to save data to HazelcastInstance and i am not able to start the server, i am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils execption.

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cache</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

While starting the server i am getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:441)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:420)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:406)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at com.portal.CacheApplication.main(CacheApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:437)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed one dependency. Try to add it to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use 2.0.0.0 spring boot parent version?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

This Missing class is in spring-aop package, if you use version **2.1.6.RELEASE** for `spring-boot-starter-parent`, `spring-aop` will be included there along with the dependencies automatically.

If you have to use 2.0.0.RELEASE, the you have to add the spring-aop dependency manually:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

change the version according to the spring version you have.

---

ALTERNATIVELY you can try adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very strange, but i deleted the repository and it worked